# How can I draw a stacked bar chart iteratively?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

So I have time series data in an array that looks like this:

```
var data = [

[{date: 2016-01-01 00:00:00, value: 52}, 
{date: 2016-01-02 00:00:00, value: 23},
{date: 2016-01-03 00:00:00, value: 42},
{date: 2016-01-04 00:00:00, value: 12,
...
],
[{date: 2016-01-01 00:00:00, value: 12}, 
{date: 2016-01-02 00:00:00, value: 42},
{date: 2016-01-03 00:00:00, value: 35},
{date: 2016-01-04 00:00:00, value: 11},
...
],
...
]
```

where data[i] represents the time series (the data is collected at 00:00:00 daily) for a component that's a part of the overall data array.

What I want to do is create a stacked bar chart for every {date, value} object so that you'd see a portion that represents `data[0]`, a portion that represents `data[1], ..., data[data.length-1]`.

What's the best way of doing this in d3? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the outline for an approach you might consider which only requires javascript and svg:

1. Subtract from each of your date values some constant earlier date value, for example unix systems use Jan 1, 1970 to compute a time difference value in days such that your time values become a series of integers.
2. In your html, specify a div such as:

   ```
   <div id="data_display"></div>
   ```
3. In your script (not complete here, but just to get the basic idea):

   ```
   var dd = document.getElementByID("data_display");
   dd.innerHTML = "<svg width='" + data.length + "' height='100'>"
   for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      dd.innerHTML += "<rect x='" + data[i] + "' y='...
   }
   dd.innerHTML += "</svg>"
   ```

   Here you just fill in the x, y, width and height of each svg rectangle with appropriate parameters from your data structure.  You can also set fill, stroke colors, etc. for the rectangles as well as add other svg objects such as text and lines, etc. to complete your chart.